# How to pass array value with post method in angular

Tags: php, angular

I want to pass array value with post method in angular to php

component.ts

```
onSubmit(orderid,username) {    
let orderdata = 
JSON.stringify(this.abc);

console.log(orderid);
this.orderservice.updatestatus(orderdata, +orderid,username).subscribe(
  res => {
    if (res.status === 'error') {          
    } else {
      //this.router.navigate(['/admin/block']);
      this.dialogRef.close();
    }
  },
  error => this.error = error
);
}
```

here this.abc is like [12,14,16]

service.ts

```
updatestatus(order, id: number,username: string) {    
return this.http.post<any>(this.serverUrl + 
'adminapi/update_order_ststus/' + id + '/' + username ,order)
  .pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
}
```

in php i want to get this array value

```
$uaCheckbox = json_decode($this->input->post('order'));
```

Comment: If you want to get the value in PHP then please show the PHP code too, also I don't think that there is a requirement to stringify `abc`

Comment: Ihave updated above please look

Comment: Your question and applied approach will be dependent on what is `$this`, `$this->input`, etc. What framework you use (if you use any). In my knowledge, examining `file_get_contents("php://input")` will help you

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion,its very helpful